# Styling jQuery UI Datepicker differently per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker on my site and wish to have it styled slightly differently depending on the page it is on.
However, I've got a little problem as the div containing the calendar isn't nested to the element which the .datepicker() function is applied to. So I cannot style it differently per page. Eg.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">...</div>
<div id="datepicker">...</div>
</body>
```

I know one solution is to id the body depending on the page but I don't really want to do that as I'm using a CMS and currently it adds classes to the wrapper div to determine which page. However as the datepicker div appears outside the wrapper I cannot style appropriately.

Is a way of configuring datepicker to create the calendar div inside a specific div, or am I going to have to id the body?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to #datepicker using jquery.

```
$("#wrapper.pageClass").nextAll("#datepicker").addClass("someClass");
```

**Edit:**

Or you could wrap #datepicker with a div using jquery. The following may work if #wrapper only has one class defined.

```
var pageClass = $("#wrapper").attr("class");
$("#datepicker").wrap("<div class='" + pageClass + "' />"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right, and it's been a long day, you have a pretty simple option available, but it does require a little extra mark-up. Give the `body` an `i`d (different id for each page):

```
body#pageOne #datepicker {/* css for pageOne */}

body#pageTwo #datepicker {/* css for pageTwo */}
```

If nothing else you get to give a bit additional semantic information; though it might not be quite as easy as you'd like.

Or, as noted in the comments (thanks [@Bryan Downing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230167/bryan-downing)) if you'd rather not add and `id` to the `body`, you can use jQuery to achieve something similar, though it depends on how your CMS applies classes to the `#wrapper`. But something like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {

        var pageClass = $('#wrapper').attr('class');

        $('#datepicker').addClass(pageClass);
    }
);
```

Then, hopefully, that should allow you to target the CSS like so:

```
#datepicker.pageOneClassName {/* css */}

#datepicker.pageTwoClassName {/* css */}
```

But obviously this relies on a coherent, and predictable/known, naming strategy being applied by the CMS. Though since this is so close to [Bryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302864/styling-jquery-ui-datepicker-differently-per-page/2303273#2303273), I'm upvoting his. Though I'll leave this in situ since it offers a slightly different take on a solution.

Comment: His question says he's trying to avoid adding an id to the body. Not sure if there's any other way to do it besides adding a class with jquery or wrapping #datepicker with a specific div.

Comment: @Bryan, +1...I can't *believe* that I missed that...d'oh! *Loooong* day... =/

Comment: Thanks! I like your way better anyway. Wrapping another DOM element around #datepicker certainly seems unnecessary. Your way of adding the class is cleaner than mine. I don't know why I didn't think of getting the class from #wrapper to add to #datepicker. I guess you weren't the only one having a long day...:P